# Weird behavior Pony mail Sinatra

Tags: ruby, email, sinatra, mailer, pony

I can send mail from my site fine using Sinatra and Pony mail.The problem lies in setting the body to use an erb template.

So my config is set like so

```
post '/' do
from = params[:name]
subject = "#{params[:name]} has contacted you"
body = erb(:mail)

Pony.mail(
:from => from,
:to => ENV["EMAIL_ADDRESS"],
:subject => subject,
:body => body,
:via => :smtp,
:via_options => {
:address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
:port                 => '587',
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:user_name            => ENV["USER_NAME"],
:password             => ENV["PASSWORD"],
:authentication       => :plain, 
:domain               => "localhost.localdomain" 
 })

flash[:notice] = "Thanks for your email. I will be in touch soon."
redirect '/success'
```

So my subject renders correclty, but the body of the message is actually returned as the html source for my webpage (as if i had right clicked view source)

My erb template is like so

```
Hello Rich,

Seems as if you have recieved an email from <%= params[:name] %> via your website.

Their email address is <%= params[:email] %>, this is what they said.

<%= params[:message] %>
```

So why isnt the body rendering the erb tempalte?

Im a bit confused here? Have i set something up incorrectly within the erb template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so for anyone else with same issue what i needed to do was tell sinatra not to use my layout file, so when setting

```
body = erb(:mail)
```

It needed to be

```
body = erb(:mail, layout: false )
```